# Android version checking and inlining of static final constants

Tags: java, android, constants

It was my understanding that and `static final` constants are inlined at compile time when using Java.

Looking at [Using the Version-Aware Component - Add the Switching Logic](http://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/using-component.html#switching-logic) and the use of [`Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html#SDK_INT) and [`Build.VERSION_CODES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION_CODES.html) confuses me, as if both these constants values are inlined at compile time this approach would be useless. What am I missing here?

Thanks :)

EDIT: does the fact they are in a static method in an abstract class change this compile-time inlining?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is inlined is constants that can be determined at compile time, such as:

```
private final int CONST = 1;
```

If you check the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/os/Build.java#Build.VERSION) (it's an old version but I suppose it has not changed much), the constants look like this:

```
public static final String SDK = getString("ro.build.version.sdk");
```

And this is the `getString` method:

```
private static String getString(String property) {
    return SystemProperties.get(property, UNKNOWN);
}
```

So the constant can't be determined at compile time.

Comment: fantastic - i should've checked the source, especially as its one extra click from the docs i linked to above - sorry! +1